# How to compare the current row with the aggregation of next n rows in Redshift?

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift

I want to retrieve results in a single SQL query using logical comparison(lead(), lag(), window) to compare a row value with the aggregation of next n rows.

For example,
I have a Books Database with the following attributes:

> id | name | date_issued | type
>   1  | abc  | 2017-05-01  | book
>   2  | def  | 2017-05-01  | book
>   3  | xyz  | 2017-05-01  | journal
>   4  | abc  | 2017-04-30  | book
>   5  | def  | 2017-04-29  | book

So, I want to compare a number of books issued on a day with the average of a number of books issued on next 3 days.

Comment: I don't think you need window functions for this. Just a subquery in your select that gets the average for the next three days...

Answer (score 2):

For your specific question, seems like you don't need the number of rows but you need a time interval because sometimes there can be 1 record per day and sometimes more. You need to get the N of books per day and then self-join it with a range condition. The query will look like this (haven't tested though):

```
with
books_by_day as (
    select date_issued as date, count(1) as books
    from books
    group by 1
)
select 
 t1.date
,t1.books as books_at_that_date
,avg(1.0*t2.books) as books_at_next_3_days
from books_by_day t1
left join books_by_day t2
on t2.date between t1.date+interval '1 day' and t1.date+interval '3 days'
group by 1,2
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could get the information you require, using a subquery in a select statement:

```
DECLARE @Books TABLE (Name VARCHAR(255), Date_Issued DATE);
INSERT @Books VALUES ('ABC', '2017-05-01'), ('DEF', '2017-05-01'), ('XYZ', '2017-05-01'), ('ABC', '2017-04-30'), ('DEF', '2017-04-29');

SELECT *,
       SoldToday = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Date_Issued),
       NextThreeDaysAverage = 
        (
            SELECT AVG(BookCount * 1.0)
            FROM
            (
                SELECT BookCount = COUNT(*)
                FROM @Books AS B2
                WHERE B2.Date_Issued > B.Date_Issued
                AND B2.Date_Issued < DATEADD(DAY, 4, B.Date_Issued)
                GROUP BY B2.Date_Issued
            ) AS T
        )
FROM @Books AS B;
```